# Should we multiply the target of actor by the importance sampling ratio when prioritized replay is applied to DDPG?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, experience-replay, ddpg

According to [PER](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf), we have to multiply the $Q$ error $\delta_i$ by the importance sampling ratio to correct the bias introduced by the imbalance sampling of PER, where importance sampling ratio is defined
$$
w_i=\left({1\over N}{1\over P(i)}\right)^\beta
$$
in which $1/N$ is the probability of drawing a sample uniformly from the buffer, and $P(i)$ is the probability of drawing a sample from PER.

I'm wondering if we have to do the same to the target of the actor when we apply PER to DDPG. That is, multiplying $-Q(s_i, \mu(s_i))$ by $w_i$, where $\mu$ is the outcome of the actor.

In my opinion, it is necessary. And I've done some experiments in the gym environment [BipedalWalker-v2](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/BipedalWalker-v2). The results, however, is quite confusing: I constantly get better performance when I do not apply importance sampling to the actor. Why would this be the case?